# NSTimer stop program iteration ( without threads )

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

How can i use a timer to just stop the program iteration for a while? The best way is using threads but how can i do it without?

Let's say i have a program

```
[myVar method1];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(test) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[myVar method2];
```

I want method2 not to be called till the selector(test) has finished its iteration... 
how can i do that?

I can set a bool into "test" and check it in method2 but is there a better way?

Comment: write [myVar method2] as last statement of method test.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two tasks that you want to happen in sequence, put them both in a serial queue. Read up about [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) for how to achieve this.